# Cannot deploy application on device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing an iOS application using Xamarin.iOS and Visual Studio.

When I debug on the iPhone Simulator, it works great. But if I try to build the app with iPhone configuration, it doesn't work.

When I build the app, the debug output display this :

```
(_BuildNativeApplication cible) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(148,3):  error : Remote build step failed. [C:...csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(148,3): error :  [C:...csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(148,3): error : Remote build step failed. [C:....csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Temps ‚coul‚ 00:01:56.41
```

However, the Mac Server Log output indicates that the build is not stopped. But it shows this error for all my views:

```
[2013-07-10 18:32:58.2] Warning: Fail moving file /Users/me/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myProj/7855596c-fbd7-487f-a36f-3b8d9c6493c0/output/Release/iPhone/myProj.app/View.nib to bundle dir: /Users/me/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myProj/7855596c-fbd7-487f-a36f-3b8d9c6493c0/bundle/myProj.app/View.nib
[2013-07-10 18:32:58.2] Warning: Exception type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
[2013-07-10 18:32:58.2] /Users/me/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myProj/7855596c-fbd7-487f-a36f-3b8d9c6493c0/output/Release/iPhone/myProj.app/View.nib does not exist
[2013-07-10 18:32:58.2]   at System.IO.File.Move (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[2013-07-10 18:32:58.2]   at MonoTouch.Tools.Tools.IBTool.MoveIBFileToBundleDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and it ends with

```
[2013-07-10 18:33:14.8] Command [Build: CommmandUrl=Build] finished (110)
```

So my idea was to take the created app file (from [2013-07-10 18:33:14.8] Command [Build: CommmandUrl=Build] finished (110) ) and add it manually on the device (with iTunes).

The install works but when I launch the app, I just can see the UI elements I created in the C# code, all the elements created in the .xib are unreachable and invisible.

After that, I tried to follow this guide for ad-hoc deployment : http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/ipa_support_for_ad_hoc_and_enterprise_deployment but the install never starts using iTunes.

Does someone have a solution to deploy a Xamarin.iOS app from Visual Studio? (I clarify I have 8 xib files in my project and all of theme are defined as InterfaceDefinition (for the generation)).

Comment: The `error : Remote build step failed` part sounds fatal to me even if the compilation continues - I'd guess you'll need to find out more about that failed step. Anything after that - invisible UIs - is likely down to those initial errors. Maybe try reproducing your problem in a small project and sending it to Xamarin support?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too after making updates.
The solution was to change the two systems for the stable version.
It was in alpha.
Do not forget to close and reopen VS. In my case did update the sdk.

Comment: actually, I need beta version for PCL support. 
Finally, I managed to launch my application, the problem was due to async/await...